# Eclipse CDT and gdb have different opinions about where source files are

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

I did the following:

1. imported a Makefile project into Eclipse CDT.
2. compiled the program from the command line using the -ggdb option of g++.
3. run the programm from the command line
4. set some breakpoints in Eclipse CDT
5. attached the Eclipse CDT debugger (gdb) to a child process that my program spawned (the child process runs a program from the same project).

At this point I get the error message in the console

> No source file named /home/oswald/Eclipse/CDT/Workspace/Project/path/to/header.h.

When I resume the programm, all my breakpoints are skipped. How can I get my breakpoints working?

Some additional notes:

- There are no shared libraries involved.
- Eclipse Indigo, gdb 7.4, Ubuntu 12.04
- Using the command line to attach gdb to the process, I can set a breakpoint to `header.h:257` (`header.h` is in folder `/home/oswald/Eclipse/CDT/Workspace/Project/path/to/`). gdb then honours this breakpoint.
- Using the command line to attach gdb to the process, I *cannot* set a breakpoint to `/home/oswald/Eclipse/CDT/Workspace/Project/path/to/header.h:257`, I get the same message from gdb as when using Eclipse CDT.
- Eclipse CDT uses the *GDB (DSF) Attach to Process Launcher*. Switching to the *Standard Attach to Process Launcher* yields an error message that the system cannot list running processes.
- The Source Lookup Path in the debug configuration is set to default (Absolute File Path, Program Realtive File Path, Project). I experimented with various other settings, but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I have written a shell script that generates a .gdbinit file that contains the appropriate directory entries:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT=/home/oswald/Eclipse/CDT/Workspace/Project

find $PROJECT -name "*.h*" -o -name "*.c*" \
  | sed 's:/[^/]*$::' \
  | sort \
  | uniq \
  | sed 's/^/directory /' > $PROJECT/.gdbinit
```

and configured the Eclipse CDT to use that .gdbinit file.

Comment: Not sure if it's totally useful to anybody, but I was able to use this to do the same thing except a bit more complicated. I needed to exclude a bunch of useless svn and CMake folders, and only include source files in two specific projects in my workspace. Here's my file:  `find $PROJECT \! \( -type d \( -path "*svn*" -o -path "*CMake*" -o -path "*.dir" \) -prune \) -type f \( -path "*/Ae9Ap9Mpi/*" -o -path "*/SpWx/*"  \)  \( -name "*.h*" -o -name "*.c*" \) \
  | sed 's:/[^/]*$::' \
  | sort \
  | uniq \
  | sed 's/^/directory /' > $PROJECT/.gdbinit`